# Nested if statement with boolean conditions around dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am struggling a bit with one of the requirements that I have. Let me try to explain.

I have a DataFrame with 150 columns. I need to check if the value in column1, column2, column3 and column4 is equal to zero. If yes, then I need to add a new column to the DataFrame and set the value to 1 else set the value to 0.

I did try to code this using a nested if condition statement but I was getting an error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, `a.bool()`, `a.item()`, `a.any()` or `a.all()`". I tried everything that I know and based on solutions provided here but couldn't get past this error.

Can you please let me know how to get this done. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: `df[['col1','col2','col3','col4']].eq(0).all(axis=1).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["new_column"]=0
df.loc[(df["column1"]==0) & (df["column2"]==0) &(df["column3"]==0) & (df["column4"]==0), ["new_column"]]=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me give it a try. But I just wanted to show what I did so that I can understand from you what was the mistake on my end.                         if (df.loc[df["column1"]==0] & df.loc[df["column2"]==0] & df.loc[df["column3"]==0] & df.loc[df["column4"]==0]:   df['new column'] = 1         else: df['new column'] = 0

Comment: why not `(df[['col1','col2','col3','col4']]==0).all(axis=1)`?

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz , Ansev and giulio. Appreciate all your help. My reputation here is not enough to accept all your answers but I just wanted to let you know that your timely help did resolve the problem. Thanks again !!

Answer (score -1):

try to use the following code (apply is a loop on the rows)

```
Df['new column']=Df.apply(lambda x: 1 if Df['column1']==1 and Df['column2']==1 and  Df['column3']==1 else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Inside ```.apply``` you should replace ```Df``` with ```x```. I think your current format would fail